# How do I use the count function with a boolean expression in Python

Tags: python, count

Why does this code output 2?  'm' is 0 (false) so why doesn't it output 0 as there is the `and` expression?

```py
s='hello'
print(s.count('m' and 'l'))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you print out `print('m' and 'l')`, you will realize that it will return `l`.

Python returns `False` for an empty string, `True` for anything else.

When you perform Boolean operations on string, the `and` operation returns the right-most element, and the `or` operation return the left most element. (Check out Logical Operators on String in Python)

You can play around with more complex examples:

```
s='helllmmko'
print(s.count('k' and 'm' and 'l')) # prints count of 'l'
print(s.count('k' or 'm' or 'l')) # prints count of 'k'
print(s.count('k' and 'm' or 'l')) # prints count of 'm'
```

Comment: so when there is no "m" in "hello" python returns true value (as it's not empty string), I thought it would be equal zero as there is no "m" in "hello" so it count zeroand boolean value would be false?

Comment: Hey sorry I missed your response. If that's what you want, then it should've been `s.count('m') and s.count('l')`. But do note that if both `'m'` and `'l'` exist in variable `s`, then it will again return the count of the latter, because other non-boolean variables follows the quirk as well (`and` returns latter, `or` returns former).

Answer (score 0):

The output of the boolean operations between the strings depends on following things:

- Python considers empty strings as having boolean value of ‘false’ and non-empty string as having boolean value of ‘true’.
- For ‘and’ operator if left value is true, then right value is checked and returned. If left value is false, then it is returned
- For ‘or’ operator if left value is true, then it is returned, otherwise if left value is false, then right value is returned.

Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-43-logical-operators-on-string-in-python/

Now to count occurrences of multiple characters in the string -
you can do something like below -
https://btechgeeks.com/count-occurrences-of-a-single-or-multiple-characters-in-string-and-find-their-index-positions/

```
# given string
string = "hello"
# given characters list which should be counted
charlist = ['m', 'l']
# traverse the charlist
for char in charlist:
    # counting the number of occurences of given character in the string
    charcount = string.count(char)
    print("count of ", char, "is :", charcount)
```

```
Output:
count of  m is : 0
count of  l is : 2
```